# Multiple thumnails are displaying when using fancybox inside bxslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, bxslider

I am using fancybox inside bxslider.When i open my image multiple thumbnails are repeating them self again and again.It happened only after i added bxslider.Any idea how that can happen. 
HTML code

```
            <!-- End .overlay -->
          </a>
          <a href="images\Gallery\picturesxlriaxiomsynergysummit\pic2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" >
          </a>
          <a href="images\Gallery\picturesxlriaxiomsynergysummit\pic3.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery1">
          </a>
          <a href="images\Gallery\picturesxlriaxiomsynergysummit\pic4.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="gallery1">
          </a>
        </article>
```

Bxslider:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.fourslide').bxSlider({
              slideWidth: 280,
              minSlides: 1,
              maxSlides: 4,
              moveSlides: 1,
              slideMargin: 0,
              adaptiveHeight:true,
              controls:true,
              auto:false
          }
          );
      }
      );
```

Comment: Some sliders make clones of images

Comment: consider adding a jsfiddle to your question

Answer (score 0):

You should remove **rel** attributes from cloned by Bxslider elements. Usually, it can be achieved using **onSliderLoad** function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fourslide').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 280,
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 4,
        moveSlides: 1,
        slideMargin: 0,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        controls: true,
        auto: false,
        onSliderLoad: function(){
            $('.bx-clone').each(function(){
                $(this).removeAttr('rel');
            })
        }       
    });
});
```